# Download my cookbook from my chef server

Tags: chef-infra

I have successfully run my own open source chef server. I setup my workstation and upload my cookbooks to my chef server. Initially I dont have and nodes i.e I didn't bootstrap a node till now. Unfortunately, my cookbook which I created and uploaded to the server was deleted in my workstation. Now I want that cookbook. How to get the cookbook from my chef server? I searched in my chef server with that cookbook name. But I cant find it? How to get my cookbook?

Comment: Looking at .Trash directory. Deleted files may be placed in Trash.

Comment: @Fumu7 It is not available in the .Trash also. Is there any way to get it from the chef server?

Comment: Did you try to find files by name for all of disks in your workstation and in your chef server? You have a little hope to find the disk in unexpected place, like trash.

Comment: May I know the uploaded cookbooks are presented in which folder of the chef server?@Fumu7

Comment: @Fumu7 I am looking in the  /var/opt/chef-server/bookshelf/data/bookshelf of my chef server. But there is folder like 00,01,06 etc. what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
knife cookbook download <cookbook name>
```

This will give you a choice of the version you wish to get from the chef-server if there's many.

If there's only one it will download the cookbook to the current directory in a directory named  coockbook-version

Comment: Will it download the cookbook from my own chef server?

Comment: It will download it from the chef server defined in your knife.rb file.

Comment: How to know uploaded cookbooks are stored in which path of the chef server?

Comment: I am looking in the /var/opt/chef-server/bookshelf/data/bookshelf of my chef server. But there is folders like 00,01,06 etc. what are they?Where are my cookbooks?

Comment: On the chef server the cookbooks are stored with berkshelf wich is a S3 like store coupled with the postgresql database.

Comment: @VijayVishnu There's no path where you'll found the cookbooks on the chef-server. The path you give, (/var/opt/chef-server/bookshelf) is the store part of bookshelf (typed berkshelf which is another tool by error in previous comment), each cookbook file is stored there by it's checksum and the bookshelf service 'package' them when a cookbook is required by a client.